# Thingsboard CE: send REST API GET request with API KEY auth

Tags: rest, authentication, iot, api-key, thingsboard

Thingsboard CE, latest version.

I'm looking for a way to make TB send the HTTP GET request to a remote server every 5 minutes. The remote server only accepts HTTP REST API requests with API KEY authorisation and is non-configurable.

TB only has "BASIC" and "PEM" authentication for the "REST API CALL" node in the rule chain. Is there a way to use API KEY auth type, or add the API KEY header manually?

Tried sending the REST API request with basic auth with username as API KEY. Response is 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new header in your rest api call node:
[image]

Replace your_api_key_name and your_api_key_value